# Wordpress custom header

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently using custom header image with randomize uploaded image option. It's working fine. Every time I reload the page it header image changes to new one. Is there a way to change that images manually like setting a timer. I'm new to wordpress. My current code is like this

In functions.php

```
$args = array(
'width'         => 1856,
'height'        => 448,
'default-image' => 'http://wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/mbuntu-11.jpg',
'uploads'       => true,);

add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

And in header.php

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('<?php header_image(); ?>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple images on the custom theme page.
Go to -> theme customize -> header images -> add images and save.
Now check on your page it's working like slider.

Comment: But it's not working as a slider. It is only changing images when page is refreshed.

Comment: If you want slider then you use available plugins form wordpress.org.

Comment: Yeah. Now I'm using plugins. Still I'm interested to know if is there any way to loop through all custom header images.